# Power series solution of $y'' + e^x y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the book of *Int. to the Ordinary Differential Equation* by Coddington, at page 130, in question 130, it is asked that

> The equation $$y'' + e^x y = 0$$ has a solution $\phi$ of the form 
>   $$\phi(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k$$ which satisfies $\phi (0) =
>  1$, $\phi'(0) = 0$. Find $c_k$.

I have plugged the Power series solution $\phi$ into the ODE, and found that every

$$\sum_{k_0}^\infty [(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2} + a_k e^x] x^k = 0$$.

However, we can interpret this result in two different way.

First; For a given $x$, the expression $$[(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2} + a_k e^x]$$ has to be zero for all $k=0,1....$,

Second; we can write this equation as

$$\sum_{k_0}^\infty [ (k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}x^k + a_k e^x x^k] = 0 $$,
and since each $x^j$ and $x^ie^x$ are linearly independent provided that $x\not = 0$, each coefficient $a_k$ has to be zero. Since in particular, we are dealing with $x = 0$, we can still reach the same conclusion as in the first case, but **what if we were dealing with $x=x_0 \not = 0$, then can we apply the first logic ?**

Comment: The Power method relies on polynomials and coefficients identification. You must replace the exponential $e^x$ by its Taylor development.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "I must" ? or it would be much sensible to do that ?

Comment: How will  you let $x$ disappear from the equations ?

Comment: You must. In what you wrote it looks like you're taking $e^x$ as part of the coefficient. That's simply wrong - a series like $\sum n e^x x^n$ is not a power series! The coefficients in a power series are _numbers_, not functions.

Comment: Your coefficients should be completely independent of $x.$

Answer (score 3):

Making $y = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$ and $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$

$$
y e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k \sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{x^j}{j!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\nu=0}^{\nu=k}\frac{a_{k-\nu}}{\nu !}x^k
$$

and then

$$
y''+e^x y \Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2} x^k +  \sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\nu=0}^{\nu=k}\frac{a_{k-\nu}}{\nu !}x^k = 0
$$

and finally

$$
(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2} + \sum_{\nu=0}^{\nu= k}\frac{1}{\nu!}a_{k-\nu} = 0
$$